# 2007 - Merge data from multiple lists in a new list

Tags: list, 2007

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

In a new site I have a list where I should merge data that comes from other lists.

There are more 5000+ records on each list.

Is there a best practice/way to do this or I have to use the datasheet view and manually copy data from each list to the new one?

Thanks!